# how to log pushbullet notifications which is showing through chrome browser extension?

Tags: pushbullet

I am using pushbullet to receive my phone notifications to my computer through pushbullet chrome extension. see Now i can get pushbulllet notifications from my phone to computer which is completely fine. but, i want to log those notifications somewhere which is very useful if i'm not in front of my computer because the notification are showing for very limited time.

basically i am a PHP developer,is there any way to achieve this using ***pushbullet*** API?.

thanks
charles